# How can I make a heads-up notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: flutter

I have tried to use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

It makes a sound, but I also want to show a heads-up notification.

**Like this.**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The notification only pops up when your app is running in the background or terminated from the recent menu. If the app is open, there won't be any heads-up notification. Follow this [link](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages) to learn more about how Android and iOS will handle notification or data based on the state of the app.

Hopefully, this helped you. Let me know if you still need help with the code or setting up the FCM.